# How do I get the top 10 results of a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql query like this:

```
with r as (
    select
        1 as reason_type_id,
        rarreason  as reason_id,
        count(*) over() count_all
    from 
        workorderlines 
    where 
        rarreason != 0
        and finalinsdate >= '2012-12-01'
)
select
    r.reason_id,
    rt.desc,
    count(r.reason_id) as num,
    round((count(r.reason_id)::float / (select count(*) as total from r) * 100.0)::numeric, 2) as pct
from r
    left outer join
        rtreasons as rt
    on
        r.reason_id = rt.rtreason
        and r.reason_type_id = rt.rtreasontype
group by
    r.reason_id,
    rt.desc
order by r.reason_id asc
```

This returns a table of results with 4 columns: the reason id, the description associated with that reason id, the number of entries having that reason id, and the percent of the total that number represents.

This table looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to do is only display the top 10 results based off the total number of entries having a reason id. However, whatever is leftover, I would like to compile into another row with a description called "Other". How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with r2 as (
  ...everything before the select list...
  dense_rank() over(order by pct) cause_rank
  ...the rest of your query...
)
select * from r2 where cause_rank < 11
union
select 
  NULL as reason_id, 
  'Other' as desc, 
  sum(r2.num) over() as num, 
  sum(r2.pct) over() as pct,
  11 as cause_rank
from r2
where cause_rank >= 11
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to change the line that gets the rank to this:
`rank() over(order by count(r.reason_id) desc) as cause_rank`

Answer (score 1):

As said above Limit and for the skipping and getting the rest use offset... [Try This Site](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/sql/select/#.UR5pg2Yo6Uk)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Postgre but SELECT TOP 10... should do the trick if you sort correctly

However about the second part: You might use a Right Join for this. Join the TOP 10 Result with the whole table data and use only the records not appearing on the left side. If you calculate the sum of those you should get your "Sum of the rest" result.

I assume that vw_my_top_10 is the view showing you the top 10 records. vw_all_records shows all records (including the top 10).

Like this:

```
SELECT SUM(a_field)
FROM vw_my_top_10
RIGHT JOIN vw_all_records
ON (vw_my_top_10.Key = vw_all_records.Key)
WHERE vw_my_top_10.Key IS NULL
```